# How to read one line of a file each time ENTER key is pressed in Linux?

Tags: bash

I am trying to come up with a script that will let the user read one line of the text file on each input of enter key until the file is done. What i tried so far:

```
while read -r line
 do read input
   if [[ -z $input ]]; then
     echo $line
 done < file.txt
```

or

```
while read -r line
echo | echo $line
done < file.txt
```

with the error:

```
sh: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
sh: -c: line 3: `done < file.txt'
```

update: i forgot "fi" at the end of "if". however,

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    read input
    if [[ -z $input ]]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < filename.txt
```

This time i am not getting any error, but it does not expect my enter input and does not print anything.

Comment: You haven't closed `if` statement with `fi`.

Comment: @Philippe true, i figured that out just now, but im still having issue with the enter input:
the code is currently like this:

while IFS= read -r line
do
    read input
    if [[ -z $input ]]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < filename.txt

still cant make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: solved by replacing

```
read input
```

with

```
read input </dev/tty
```

Answer (score 0):

`read` reads from standard input by default. Your standard input is set to a file (`< filename.txt`). bash however lets you specify the fd to read from:

```
$ cat test
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

You received only some lines from `filename.txt` while others are consumed by `read -r line`:

```
$ while IFS= read line; do
    read line
    echo $line
  done < test
line 2
```

Here's how to use a different fd:

```
$ while IFS= read -u4 line; do
    read -s
    echo $line
  done 4< test
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

See man page of bash (or whatever shell you are using) for the `read` command.